# how to create a new array from two arrays, and take from one the length and from other the values?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have two arrays:

```
list_a = [20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 20,21, 23, 20, 23, 24]
list_b = [120, 121, 122, 123, 124]
```

and I want to create the next array from those two arrays like so:

```
newList = [120, 120, 120, 121, 121, 122, 120, 121, 123, 120, 123, 124]
```

so the first number from the first array will replaced by value with 120, but not in the length of the 20, and so on, and afterwards when 20 is also located, it will replace it with the first number also

I tried a lot of stuff, nothing worked...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: i didnt ment to add 100, the numbers doesnt matter. it could be: list_b = [48, 49, 50, 52, 54], and the result would be: newList = [48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 50, 48, 49, 52, 48, 52, 54]

Comment: How would 20 20 20 .... 20  become 48 48 48 .... 48? Is it just the repeating numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specs were not clear

Try this, we create a unique list of list_a and use the placement of each to index into list_b

```js
const list_a = [20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 20, 21, 23, 20, 23, 24]
const list_b = [120, 121, 122, 123, 124]
const idxList = [...new Set(list_a)]; // unique and placements
const newList = list_a.map(num => {
  const idx = idxList.indexOf(num)
  return list_b[idx]
});

console.log(newList)
```

Comment: is thier a way to transform the second selotion to numbers back again?

Comment: or to do this with integers only and not converting it to strings? thank you very much

Comment: with this solution: const strListB = list_b.map(String); // make strings

newList = list_a.map(num => {
  const strA = num.toString();
  return strListB.find(strB => strB.endsWith(strA))
});
console.log(newList)

Comment: @dAn_d Try my last version

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for the values and keep an index of unseen values.

```js
const
    list_a = [20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 20, 21, 23, 20, 23, 24],
    list_b = [120, 121, 122, 123, 124],
    result = list_a.map(
        ((values, i) => v => values[v] ?? (values[v] = list_b[i++]))
        ({}, 0)
    );
    
console.log(...result);
console.log(...[120, 120, 120, 121, 121, 122, 120, 121, 123, 120, 123, 124]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more elegant solution with [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) but the first thing that came to my mind was to make a `hash map` first and then `map` through the `list_a` `array`.

This solution allows for any values in `list_b` **but** requires that the following condition is met:

```
unique_values_list_b.length >= unique_values_list_a
```

Hope this helps or sends you in the right direction.

```js
(function main () {
    const list_a = [20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 20,21, 23, 20, 23, 24]
    const list_b = [120, 121, 122, 123, 124]

    let i = 0
    const hash = new Map([])

    // setting up a hash
    for(let a of list_a){
        if(hash.has(a)) continue
    
        hash.set(a, list_b[i++])        
    }


    // creating your new list

    const newList = list_a.map(element => hash.get(element))
    console.log(newList)
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let list_a = [20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 20, 21, 23, 20, 23, 24];
let list_b = [120, 121, 122, 123, 124];

let output = list_a.map((e) => {
  return parseInt('1' + e);
});

console.log(output);
```